# Under what circumstances do ZeroMQ sockets drop or fail to deliver messages?

Tags: zeromq

Is there some sort of a specification or other explanation that describes the normal cases where you can expect a message sent on a ZeroMQ socket to not be received by ( all ) the listening processes, for each communication type?

For example I have an experimental program which basically assumes that all subscribers to a `PUB` socket receive all messages sent on that socket ( after an initialization handshake ).  I would like to understand the cases where that assumption may be false.  Thanks, and sorry if this has already been asked.

Answer (score 10):

The chart in this image is a good guide to when zmq sockets drop messages: https://raw.github.com/imatix/zguide/master/images/fig25.png

For more information, you might want to read http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all#Missing-Message-Problem-Solver