# Detect dropped messages in ZeroMQ Queues

Tags: zeromq

Since it does not seem to be possible to query/inspect the underlying ZeroMQ queues/buffers  sockets to see how much they are utilized, is there some way to detect when a message is dropped due to full buffers in a Publisher socket when sent/queued?

For example, if the publisher queue is full, the `zmq_send` operation will simply drop the message.

Basically, what I want to achieve is a way to detect situations where the queues are getting stressed and/or full to be able to (later on) tune the solution to work better. One alternative way would be to add a sequence number to each message and do a simple calculation in the subscriber but I can never be sure that a message was lost due to full buffers in the publisher.

Comment: There is a really nice feed that answers: Under what circumstances do zeromq sockets drop or fail to deliver messages? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909909/under-what-circumstances-do-zeromq-sockets-drop-or-fail-to-deliver-messages

Maybe it is interesting for u

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an example for this in the ZeroMQ Guide (which you should read and digest if you want to use 0MQ happily): http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Slow-Subscriber-Detection-Suicidal-Snail-Pattern

The mechanism is as you answered yourself, to add a sequence number in the message, and allow the subscriber to detect gaps and take appropriate action. For most pubsub scenarios you can raise the default HWM, which is 1,000, to something much higher; it depends on your average message size.

Comment: RIP Pieter. But this answer is unacceptable. ZMQ should give us a way to check if a message was sent or not.

Comment: @Pieter Hintjens How did you find anything in the doc you linked to? It is a giant wall of text... How can I know if there is maybe anything else usefull there?
Anyway, I need to know where problems originate. I need to know the load on each queue. Simply killing the first one that gets overloaded won't help me find the problem

Comment: @Gulzar I believe Pieter wrote that text, the book, and much of zmq in-general. The digital version of the book might make text searches easier? Not sure.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post but here is what I did when recently facing the same issue.

I opted to use a `DEALER/ROUTER` and set the **`ZMQ_SNDHWM`** option to 1. Also I provided the timeout parameter on each **`zmq_send()`**. The timeout could be anything between 10 ms to 3 seconds, depending on what your scenario is ( a local or remote send ).

If the message is not sent within the timeout or the send-buffer is full the `zmq_send()` will return false. That enabled me to set up a retry queue in front of zmq. I know it's not a perfect solution but for me it worked just fine. What puzzles me though is the meaning of true/false returned by the `DEALER`-socket `zmq_send()`. I have not been able to find the answer to that question. Whether it indicates that the message has been buffered or that the message has been delivered to the `ROUTER` has eluded me. In my case I got the results needed anyway.

Just for the record this was done using netmq but I guess it applies to ZeroMQ as well.

I do agree wtih james though. ZeroMQ ( and netmq ) should at least provide a way to inspect the queue ( and get the messages out ) and also a way to tell the various sockets not to drop messages. The best option would be to send messages not delivered in timely fashion according to the configured options to some sort of deadletter queue. The deadletter queue could then be handled separately.