# C++ non C and clear way to send std::string over network

Tags: c++, networking

I'm looking for a method to send a std::string across a TCP / IP network. It must be platform independent.

The methods I've looked at are:

- C sockets - messy.
- boost::asio - too complicated
- Qt - requires you to inherit QObject and also only single threaded.

What is the simplest, yet strongest method to do this?

Also some example code using the given library for both server side and client side functions, to connect and transfer a std::string would be amazing!

Comment: You can use ZeroMQ instead of C sockets.

Comment: if you fill comfortably with QT , you do not need to inherit your data from QObject and you can also protect your socket class simply with a mutex and use it from a multithread environment. I don't think you can find a lib that let you push data into a socket without using a blocking object like a mutex or semaphore...

Comment: This is a question seeking a recommendation for a tool/library, which is a category that is [not considered On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per the help center due to opinions and debate vs. focused answers.  Per that: @ForceBru ZeroMQ may not count as "strong", given the relatively weak guarantee that it will only deliver a message completely or not not at all, causing you to need to [re-implement TCP with sequence numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891682/) if you need delivery guarantees of some kind.  Something to know.

Comment: @HostileFork With all due respect, Sir, you have added a lot "un-said" requirements to the original post & 've assumed these to be a part of the ( otherwise rather weak ) Task Definition. Yes, there are other opinions out there about what shall be and what need not be a part of a **"strong"** solution, nevertheless, a guaranteed delivery need not be a part of the message delivery layer of the (undefined) application architecture. Having spent years in non-stop business critical system design / implementation, one may design a smart / light-weight messaging layer & add delivery controls ad-hoc

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com & show some respect** to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far**. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by strongest ? Fastest ? Simpliest ?
The server (eg receiver of the string) :

- should it be sync or async ?
- does it have to answer something or not ?

The anwsers should drive your choice.

If you want something very simple, look for "portable telnet c++ server client", you will get a lot of libs and code samples.

However, to answer your question, here are some portable libs:

- [Sockets lib, here is a sample](http://www.alhem.net/Sockets/tutorial/using1a.html)
- [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual) : may be overkill for a so simple use case, but simple to use anyway

Answer (score 0):

the question is a bit ambiguous :

a) what do you mean by send "std::string" over the network? do you want to completely serialize this object, send it and deserialize it in the other side? or simply send the actual text and build it again as std::string (which is in my opinion simpler and preferred)?

b) it sounds like your question is really "what platforms/libraries there are out there for networking?".

for a : if you decide on sending a text and re-building it as std::string , then you have no problem, just send the text as C-string. you might want to wrap it with some data format as XML or JSON in order to make sure the text was sent correctly. if you DO want to serialize std::string , then there is no clean way of doing so. you might want to reinterpret_cast the object into char array , send it in this way and writing it to some memory. this is not safe or simple.

for b : there are many libraries out there. POCO is well known and quit ok. 
JUCE is a simple ,cross platform , modern C++ platform which support object-oriented Socket classes. you might want to use them as well.